# Promise Chain getting slow after a few seconds

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a 2000 zip codes list in a .txt file and for each of them I need to make some requests (two or three).

But around 200 lines tested, the script starts to getting very very slow. The first 200 are very fast. Of course I understand that the way I'm doing it, the requests are made in parallel for all the lines of the txt, and I also know that the problem is probably because the promises are not being resolved/killed. How could I resolve this? Does anyone have any good study material on this?

```
const axios = require('axios')
const chalk = require('chalk')
const fs = require('fs')
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')()

const getLocalization = async (zip) => {
  const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `viacep.com.br/ws/${zip}/json`,
  }
  try {
    const res = await axios(config)
    return res
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

const getCity = async (zip) => {
  // ... example
}

const main = async (zip) => {
  const disponibility = await getLocalization(zip)
  if (disponibility) {
    getCity(zip)
  } else {
    console.log('ZIP not Found')
  }
}

console.log(chalk.yellow('# Database Path:'))
const filename = prompt('$ ')
const parsered = fs.readFileSync(filename.includes('.txt') ? filename : `${filename}.txt`, 'utf8').split('\n')

for (i = 0; i < parsered.length; i++) {
  const trimmedLine = parsered[i].trim().split('|')[0]
  main(trimmedLine)
}
```

Comment: "*I also know that the problem is probably because the promises are not being resolved/killed*" how do you know that? To me, it seems the problem is simply that too many things are happening and can't be processed all at the same time effectively. Not anything to do with how promises are handled, or that promises remain unresolved (I see no evidence of that, either).

Comment: I monitored the memory/cpu usage and there is nothing strange, the requests are not long, 1s each, as there are two requests, 2s each line. I suspect that some promises are not being resolved, and are blocking the pool.

Comment: Promises not being resolved blocks nothing. An unresolved promise will just hang around forever but there is no pool of promises. Promises are not *threads*. Just a notification mechanism for an asynchronous task running *somewhere*. If you have a doorbell and nobody rings it, that doesn't "block" people from coming to your house. If the notification mechanism not being used, it doesn't makes sense to say that it stops other things happening that don't rely on it.

Comment: Got it, so the problem isn't unresolved promises blocking execution in some way. It wouldn't be a problem if the script was just slow, but it freezes after about 300 lines processing a file that has 2000. I really can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I also thought it would be the subsequent axios calls, in the case of 2000 lines it would be 4000 requests, but apparently that's not the problem either

Comment: Could be many things. It could be that you're running into limit of how many concurrent network connections you can have at the same time. It could be that whatever `await axios(config)` calls throttles you for too many requests after a while. Or maybe it doesn't throttle you intentionally, just can't handle that many at once and *it* is being slow. Could be something else somewhere, as well.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help, it helped a lot, I'll try and study what it can be

Comment: Sorry to come back to this topic, but today it got even weirder. I decided to duplicate the original list (there were 2000 lines, ctrl a + ctrl c + ctrl v it and it became 4000) and surprisingly, instead of freezing around 1800, freezed around 3800. So I decided to duplicate again (8000 lines), and now, freezed around 7800!